# NUnit TestCaseSource with parameters?

Tags: c#, tdd, nunit

I have multiple test classes that implement an empty interface (`ITest`, expanded with `IEnumerable`).

Interface:

```
public interface ITest : IEnumerable
{
}
```

TestDataSource with a description:

```
[Description("TestSourceName")]
public class MyTests : ITest
{    
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return "123";
        yield return "456";
    }
}
```

`TestDataProvider` class that will be used as `TestDataSource` in NUnit,
I'm using reflection to get the right `TestDataSource` object:

```cs
public class TestDataProvider : IEnumerable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
            yield break;

        var testdata = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                .GetTypes()
                .Where(mytype => mytype.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ITest)))
                .Where(mytype => ((DescriptionAttribute)mytype.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)[0])
                .Description.ToLower() == Name.ToLower());

        yield return ((IEnumerable)testdata).GetEnumerator();

    }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

Now I wonder how I can pass `TestSourceName` to the `TestDataSource` for NUnit?

```
[TestCaseSource(typeof(TestDataProvider)), TestCaseSourceAttribute("TestSourceName")]
public void TestTestDataProvider()
{
    // here we will have the TestDataSource object given by TestDataProvider 
    // using parameter/attribute? "TestSourceName"
}
```

Comment: See if this can be of any help: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/30779861/47458][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30779861/47458

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach you could take is to use NUnit [TheoryAttribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=theory&r=2.5).  Theories are still part of the upcoming 3.0 release as well.

Roughly based on the examples you gave, here is an example of a working Theory based test which uses the data from the [DataPointsAttribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=datapoint&r=2.5) as parameters to the test method.

```cs
[Description("TestSource2")]
public class TestData1 : ITest
{
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return "123";
        yield return "456";
    }
}

[Description("TestSource1")]
public class TestData2 : ITest
{
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return 33;
        yield return 44;
    }
}

public class TestDataProviderFixture
{
    [Datapoints] 
    public string[] SourceNames = {"TestSource1", "TestSource2"};

    [Theory]
    public void TestTestDataProvider(string sourceName)
    {
        var provider = new TestDataProvider();
        var data = provider.GetEnumerator(sourceName);

        if (sourceName == "TestSource1")
        {
            while (data.MoveNext())
            {
                //Do Stuff
            }
        }
        else if (sourceName == "TestSource2")
        {
            while (data.MoveNext())
            {
            //Do Stuff
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Assert.Fail();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tanks BgRVa, I'll give 3.0 a try.